# How to return array from function in NXC?

Tags: nxt, nxc

How to return array from function in NXC? I tried the following

```
string[] strsplit(string str)
{
      string parts[2] = {"1", "2"};
      return parts;
}
```

but I get `Variable name expected`. Why?

P.S. if there built-in **split** function I'll be glad to here about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string[]` cannot be a return type in C or C++, and hence NXC.

See the NXC API for [`SubStr()`](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/nxcdoc/nxcapi/group__cstring_a_p_i_ga35d32335d12e1f453977797ad5a1d861.html), to help in 'splitting' strings.

---

Try:

```
void strspilt(string &out[], string str, unsigned int idx)
{
    ArrayInit(out, "", 2);

    out[0] = SubStr(str, 0, idx);
    out[1] = SubStr(str, idx, strlen(str) - idx);
}
```